# How to find value from nested object with key wildcard in Compass MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, terminal, mongodb-compass

I have one nested object in Compass MongoDB:

```
{
"data_rm": {
    "pembiayaan": {
        "name": "pembiayaan",
        "value": "asuransi",
        "type": "radio",
        "title": ""
    },
    "asuransi": {
        "name": "asuransi",
        "value": "ADMEDIKA - FWD LIFE INDONESIA (FINANSIAL WIRAMITRA DANADYAKSA, PT)",
        "type": "select-one",
        "text": "ADMEDIKA - FWD LIFE INDONESIA (FINANSIAL WIRAMITRA DANADYAKSA, PT)",
        "title": ""
    },
    "informasi_diperoleh_dari": {
        "name": "informasi_diperoleh_dari",
        "value": "pasien",
        "type": "radio",
        "title": ""
    },
    "cara_datang": {
        "name": "cara_datang",
        "value": "sendiri",
        "type": "radio",
        "title": ""
    },
    "nama_pengantar": {
        "name": "nama_pengantar",
        "value": "Tn. BAGUS",
        "type": "text",
        "title": ""
    },
    "no_telp_pengantar": {
        "name": "no_telp_pengantar",
        "value": "0813xxxxxxxx",
        "type": "text",
        "title": ""
    }
}
```

How did I return the document WHERE type is "select-one"? (I want to find which key in data_rm has the type of select-one)

** EDIT **

The desired output is:

```json
  {
    data_rm: {
      "asuransi": {
        "name": "asuransi",
        "value": "ADMEDIKA - FWD LIFE INDONESIA (FINANSIAL WIRAMITRA DANADYAKSA, PT)",
        "type": "select-one",
        "text": "ADMEDIKA - FWD LIFE INDONESIA (FINANSIAL WIRAMITRA DANADYAKSA, PT)",
        "title": ""
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Would you show your desired output?

Comment: @rickhg12hs the desired output is {data_rm: {"asuransi": {
        "name": "asuransi",
        "value": "ADMEDIKA - FWD LIFE INDONESIA (FINANSIAL WIRAMITRA DANADYAKSA, PT)",
        "type": "select-one",
        "text": "ADMEDIKA - FWD LIFE INDONESIA (FINANSIAL WIRAMITRA DANADYAKSA, PT)",
        "title": ""
    }}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.  In Compass you can enter each stage of the aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": { "rmArray": { "$objectToArray": "$data_rm" } }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "selOne": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$rmArray",
          "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.v.type", "select-one" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": { "data_rm": {"$arrayToObject": "$selOne" } }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MCj0Pnz4Lfo).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works as desired! Btw, can you send me the link on where to learn all of this mongodb query? Tbh, I find myself struggling in understanding all of this command.

Comment: Glad it helped!  You could start with the [MongoDB reference manual](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/crud/) or the tutorials there.  You'll also learn a lot from answering questions here and trying things on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MCj0Pnz4Lfo) and in Compass like you have done.  I know I have.